How to apply multiple effects on one widget in pyqt?
I want to apply a QGraphicsDropShadowEffect and a QGraphicsOpacityEffect in my PyQt6 application. My goal is to have a widget, that has the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect and that I can animate the widget's opacity to fade it in and out depending on the user's action.
To enable the effects with PyQt6 I use the setGraphicsEffect method of the widget. Because PyQt6 does not allow to set multiple effects on the same widget, I put parts of the widget in a container. I apply the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect to a specific widget and the QGraphicsOpacityEffect to the whole container. Because the opacity is set to 0.7 by default (see this) I want to set it to 1.0 after the effect is created. Here, I get an error.
Here is a minimal example which produces the error:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
)
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class CircleWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the main layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        # Create a label to act as the circle with text
        self.circle_label = QLabel("Text")
        self.circle_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.circle_label.setFixedSize(100, 100)  # Set size to create a circle
        self.circle_label.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QLabel {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 50px;  /* Half of the width/height to create a circle */
                font-size: 20px;
            }
            """
        )

        # Create and set the drop shadow effect
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        shadow.setBlurRadius(15)
        shadow.setOffset(5, 5)
        shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 160))  # Set shadow color with some transparency
        self.circle_label.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        # Create a container widget to apply opacity effect
        container = QWidget()
        container_layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
        container_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        container_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        container_layout.addWidget(self.circle_label)

        # Create and set the opacity effect on the container
        opacity_effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        opacity_effect.setOpacity(1.0)  # Set the desired opacity level
        container.setGraphicsEffect(opacity_effect)

        # Add the container with the label to the main layout
        layout.addWidget(container)

        # Set the layout to the main window
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Circle with Effects")
        self.setFixedSize(200, 200)

# Initialize the application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = CircleWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())

The error I get:
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QWidgetEffectSourcePrivate::pixmap: Painter not active
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active

The strange thing is, that I do not get the error, if I set the opacity to a slightly smaller value, e.g. 0.99.
I am running this app on Ubuntu 24.04.
So I don't know whether this is a bug or if I am not applying (or stacking) the effects correctly.

I can reproduce it on Linux, both PySide and PyQt (5 and 6). Seems to be related to QTBUG-60231, which was marked as resolved in Qt5, but some related reports for newer versions exist, so a change in the code may have caused a regression that "unfixed" it. You may consider checking that report, the other linked in it and search for other similar reports, and eventually file your own including references to your research.

In the meantime, if you really need to set an effect that can have 1.0 opacity, create a subclass that overrides setOpacity() (or internally connects to opacityChanged) and call the effect setEnabled(opacity < 1).
